# Should I put an experimental experience from master' degree as a skillset in my CV after a computational PhD?

Tags: application, postdocs, cv

I am applying for mechanical engineering and materials engineering postdoc positions. I mostly apply for computational research positions but sometimes I apply where they are looking for experimentalists with some computational experience as well.  **Can I mention the following as a skillset in the CV without being misleading?**

My PhD was in computational materials science where I did not do any experiments. However in 2013, I completed master's degree where I had done quite a significant amount of experimental work. I did scanning electron microscopy, xray diffraction experiments and mechanical testing. I did not do those during my PhD. I remember how to analyze the results, but I don't remember how to operate the machines anymore.

**Under such scenario, should I mention experimental methods as an experience in my CV?**

Currently, I mentioned these in following way:

```
>     Research Skills
>     Computational: Experienced in nonlinear Finite Element Analysis (FEA)....blah blah blah
>     • Tools: Python, Fortran, blah blah
>     • Packages: Scikit-Learn, blah blah
>     
>     Experimental: Proficient in metallurgical polishing and mechanical testing; Experienced in materials-characterization methods: Scanning
> Electron Microscopy, Electron Backscatter Diffraction (EBSD).
```

Comment: If you were put in front of one of those machines, would you only be able to stare at it blankly?

Comment: Yes, I won't be able to operate them on the fly. But I would be able to learn it quickly, know the technicalities and somewhat interpret the results (though not expertly).

Comment: Then I see no issue. Machines aren't all the same anyways.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is a good idea to list all positive/relevant experience. But if you are worried about it being misleading, just put a date on the item, listing when the project ended, or the start and end dates. People can do their own math.

But leaving it out entirely seems a mistake to me.